# How to show only ground overly image on google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, scroll, zooming

I am developing one application. I have added an image by ground overly on google map.
Can we show only that image on google map? I don't want to show other areas on the map.

I applied:

```
googleMap.setMinZoomPreference(18f);
googleMap.setMaxZoomPreference(18f);
googleMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(newarkBounds1);
```

But is it change device wise.

I set ground overly by this code

```
mGroundOverlayRotated = googleMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                .image(mImages.get(0))
                //.position(NEWARK, 210.29f, 242.87f)
                .positionFromBounds(newarkBounds)
        );
```

I want to set like user can zoom, scroll and etc in only that area or ground.
Let me know if any one faces this. Thank you.

Comment: Visit this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31361273/6021469

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan I am looking solution for Android. if possible then provide me else I am trying to explore your provided link and javascript. Thank you.